# Почему в PHP, когда пишут в ООП стиле создают экземпляр объекта?

Tags: php, ооп

Как я сейчас делаю.
Создаю файл MySQL.php (опустим пространства имен, папку где создаю, композер и т.д.)

```
<?php
class MySQL
{

// Подключение к БД.
    static function connectToBase()
    {
// Тут код подключения.
    return $mysqli;
    }

// Выполнение mySQL запроса.
    static function mySQLQuery($query)
    {
        $mysqli = self::connectToBase();
// Тут код выполнения запроса.
    }

}
```

Далее в индексе, через который идет подключение всех страниц (вроде называют это роутер, контроллер), подключаю этот файл.
Теперь в любом файле моего проекта мне достаточно просто вызвать

```
$sqlResult=MySQL::mySQLQuery('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES value');
```

Так как методы в классе MySQL статические, мне не нужно создавать экземпляр класса.
Мне не нужно контролировать чтобы он был один (синглтон), не нужно заботиться о возможной утечке памяти (ну а вдруг? что то же создали, а так нет экземпляра нечему и "течь").

Тем не менее мне говорят, что я пишу не в ООП стиле. И по непонятной мне причине, я должен создавать экземпляры классов.
Также мне говорят, что я постоянно подключаюсь к БД.

Почему в PHP, когда пишут в ООП стиле создают экземпляр объекта?

Comment: отложим вопрос о БД. Вот у вас есть пользователи. вам нужна коллекция из 500 сотрудников организации  причём кто-то из них Админ, кто-то Программист, кто-то Уборщица, кто-то Водитель. Для каждого будет своя специфичная логика начисления ЗП и штатного расписания. Как вы реализуете список сотрудников и дальнейший их расчёт по ЗП на статике?

Comment: Потому что это не ООП, а инкапсуляция. Это всего лишь один из аспектов ООП, и называть такой подход ООП - мало у кого язык повернется.

Comment: если вы в каждом запросе выполняете `connectToDb` и при этом линк к базе не сохраненн в статический член класса и не проверяется на наличие, то логично вроде предположить, что с каждым запросом вы делаете новое подключение?

Comment: Могут ли быть полностью статические классы - могут. будет ли это ООП - будет. Вопрос в том, что если у вас весь проект построен на статических классах, то это несколько странно, таки первая О в ООП это Объект, а не Класс. Статика для синглтона в целом проста в использовании, это нормально. Не нормально, когда делаете это повсеместно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - статика близка к процедурному программированию. Нет ни каких проблем написать программу в процедурном стиле. 

Для создания списка сотрудников, я создам двумерный массив. Далее сделаю выборку из БД и в первый элемент массива передам ФИО, во второй должность. Далее, перебирая массив, в зависимости от должности я буду вызывать нужный метод расчета ЗП.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков - инкапсуляция одна из парадигм ООП. В своем проекте я наследуюсь от классов - для этого не надо создавать экземпляры, просто наследую статические методы базового класса в производном. Иногда использую абстракцию.

Comment: @teran - "таки первая О в ООП это Объект, а не Класс" - так есть ещё и интерфейс и много чего ещё.
Кстати объект, если я не ошибаюсь, как раз есть "статическая сущность" на куче - то есть при создании экземпляра класса код класса храниться в единственном виде, вне зависимости сколько экземпляров мы создали (хорошо объяснено в С#). И это логично -не забивать же память одинаковым кодом. 

"если вы в каждом запросе выполняете connectToDb" - да именно так. Но идею понял.

Comment: @Иван, то что делает автор - инкапсуляция, т.е. разбивает код и данные на составные части группируя по некой принадлежности. К ООП это имеет непосредственное отношение как базовая составляющая, но является ли это ООП - и да и нет. ООП это больше чем инкапсуляция, но инкапсуляция это часть ООП, так что если применять только этот один прием - то это только инкапсуляция, а если использовать не один прием а несколько разных(наследование\включения\абстракции\инкапсуляцию\...) - тогда уже это будет ООП :)

Comment: @Иван "*статика близка к процедурному программированию.......... нужный метод расчета ЗП*" --- Тогда это будет не ООП. Вы определитесь что вам нужно: ООП или"как я привык". Если второе - то вам и классы-то не нужны и статика не нужна и вот это вот всё вам не нужно.

Comment: з.ы. объектно ориентированное, выше вам уже это написали, не классово, а объектно :) вы играетесь в странную пародию на ООП без объектов, причем скорее всего натыкаясь на кучу граблей(одни из которых вы озвучили даже в своем вопросе, "постоянно подключаюсь к бд", и эта ошибка даже не возникла бы у вас воспользуйтесь вы паттерном синглтон :)

Comment: @Иван "*В своем проекте я наследуюсь от классов - для этого не надо создавать экземпляры, просто наследую статические методы базового класса в производном*" --- как при таком подходе вы храните коллекцию данных какого-то типа? Например коллекцию тех же пользователей, со своими уникальными данными?

Comment: "*Почему в PHP, когда пишут в ООП стиле создают экземпляр объекта?*"  --- ответ уже в самом вопросе. Потому что ООП - это ОБЪЕКТНОЕ программирование :D